# Events in Polkadot.js/api

Tags: polkadot-js, events

I am trying to call api.events.staking.Withdrawn.is in polkadot.js/api.

Docs: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events#withdrawnaccountid32-u128

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-architecture-vrhyqm?file=/index.js

It is not working and causing isssue.

```
const provider = new WsProvider("wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io");
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
const validator = "CaKh7HmPMXxv22GnLgjEZxWHBUu7y7Twf2k8mP3mxpLYTH4";
const response = await api.events.staking.Withdrawn.is(validator, "50");
```

Error

```
2022-05-19 17:41:35        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: mmr_generateBatchProof
(node:2206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.is (/sandbox/node_modules/@polkadot/types/cjs/metadata/decorate/events/index.js:44:60)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/sandbox/index.js:10:57)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2206) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Please dont post a link to some external code sandbox. Please include the code snippet and the actual error that is returned in this question.

Comment: I updated question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `api.event.<pallet>.<event>.is(Event)` is not used to create an event, rather it is used to check if an emitted event is of a specific type, returning true if this is the case. Additionally the `api.event.<pallet>.<event>` exposed the metadata for the event, so the signature [looks like this](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/baa2caae686b725a9c71cd147bdb138dd3c390f2/packages/types/src/metadata/decorate/types.ts#L19-L23) -

```js
interface IsEvent <T extends AnyTuple> {
  readonly meta: EventMetadataLatest;

  is: (event: IEvent<AnyTuple>) => event is IEvent<T>;
}
```

Assuming you have read `query.system.events` and you have an `Vec<EventRecord>`, you can use this to iterate through and check if an event is a specific type. (Alternatively you can always look for the `section` & `method` on this event and do string matching)

On the middleware/API side, you never need to create events - these are only emitted by the runtime.

Comment: This syntax `api.event.<pallet>.<event>.is(Event)`, I assume can't be used for custom pallets right?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are passing the "amount" argument as a 'string' in api.events.staking.Withdrawn.is(validator, "50") ?

According to the docs it should be a u128, or in js, I think it a 'number'.

Comment: Can you send me example u128 type amount value? @CustomBlink

Comment: While not applicable here specifically, it is a good question. The JS API will detect and convert formats as/when needed. So where number inputs are required, it would accept: number, BN, BigInt, string (decimal numbers), hex (0x prefixed) and will do the conversion as required.